# vue-cli-service can't resolve import with custom alias in *.vue

Tags: typescript, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli-3, vue-loader

first of all I know that there are a lot of similar questions to this one, but all of those I checked are either not my exact problem or outdated (e.g. ppl asking for how to add `@/` that now is there by default).

**What is my Goal/Problem?**

I have some `*.ts` files that are generated into `target/generated-typescript` instead of `src/` where my "handwritten" code is located.

In my tsconfig.json i added `"$/*": [ "target/generated-typescript/*" ]` analog to the configuration of the `@/*` path alias. In regular `*.ts` files i can use `$/my_ts_file` for imports. now i wanted to use such a file to import stuff into a `*.vue` file.

In IntelliJ everything is OK as in there is no error marked at the import. but when starting `vue-cli-service serve` (or build) i get the following error in the run console:

```
This dependency was not found:

* $/my_ts_file in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--13-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0
-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/MyvueComponent.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&
```

and a similar one in the browser:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/views/MyvueComponent.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts& (./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--13-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/MyvueComponent.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '$/my_ts_file' in 'C:\path\to\my\proj\src\views'
```

**My attempt to fix the problem**

I added the following block to my `vue.config.js` as suggested by similar questions asking for `@/` imports to work.

```
chainWebpack: config => {
    config.resolve
        .alias
        .set('$', config.store.get('context') + '\\target\\generated-typescript')
},
```

this correctly adds the alias as the output of `console.log(config.resolve.alias.store)` shows. the lines of '@' and '$' are identical except for `src` vs my target directory. I also tried to use `configureWebpack` instead of `chainWebpack` but both are not working.

**Environment**
Window Server 2012 Standard
Node 12.6.0
NPM 6.9.0
vue-cli 3.10.0
vue 2.6.10